# Error in view page source " redundancy blank line " in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I encountered a line overflow error when viewing the page source.

I just started to learn and build websites on wordpress platform.

I encountered a line overflow error when viewing the page source. How to fix it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2M40.png)

Comment: Please share more details regarding the issue you are facing and relevant code snippets will make your post more readable.

Answer (score 0):

It usually happens because of whitespaces or line-breaks after ?> closing tags.

First: Open your theme's functions.php, go to bottom line, and make sure there is no white space after ?> closing tag. And you can also check functions.php's top and middle parts as well. Just look for ?> closing tags where there is some space or line break after it.

Second: If there is not. Then go to plugins section, disable/enable plugins one-by-one. After each disabling check the source again - until you find that blank space disappeared. After finding that plugin, go to its php files and check where white space is (after ?> closing tags)